# How to allow the user edit input fields that contain html tags

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I am using PHP5 and some of the fields in the database contain HTML tags. The user should be able to edit these and save them as part of the form. Let's take a simple example.

I have a field called `link` that comes from the database and contains an HTML link tags such as:

```
$link = "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">go to google</a>";
```

In my html form I have an input field that will allow the user to edit the $link contents(including tags) - I use Smarty templating engine so hence the `{$link}` notation

```
<input name="link" id="link" value="{$link}" />
```

Issue I have now is that the first time the link field gets displayed as is, so with tags and all, but when the user saves to the database and page refreshes, I see the words "go to google", so the tags get stripped out. Upon closer inspection, that is what is saved in the database as well.

How do I deal with this situation, given the simple example above?

Comment: have you tried escaping `<=&lt;` and `>=&gt;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the PHP function `htmlentities($link)` to scape those tags.

Here is the [Manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: where do I use it? Please provide the full code of how this should look like. Is used before displaying it on the page? After clicking submit on the form? thanks.

Comment: When you display it on the page `<input name="link" id="link" value="{htmlentities($link)}" />`

Comment: will it save the tags to the database? I used htmlspecialchars function before and it displayed the text with tags but still stripped them when saving to DB. So, upon spitting out $_POST I saw the words "go to google" and no tags. ANd I don't have control of what happens between the user pressing submit and when the page refreshes.

Comment: Yes, the tags will be saved to the database, but you don't need to use this function when saving, the tags will be inside quotes. Then, you'll have the value of `link` on your database (with the html tags), simply display it on the page (using `htmlentities`).